# php exec missing output

Tags: php, python, exec, nltk

I am trying to execute the python script for POS tagging through PHP. 
But its not returning the full output.

**Python script:**

```
import nltk
import sys

text = sys.argv[1]

tokenize_into_words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

print text

result = nltk.pos_tag(tokenize_into_words)

print result

print "Done!"
```

**PHP script**

```
$cmd = 'python /Library/WebServer/Documents/varticle/vcmdpos.py ' . $string2;

$tmp = exec($cmd,$output);

print_r($output);
```

**Command:**

python /Library/WebServer/Documents/varticle/vcmdpos.py Scientists

**Observed Output:**

Array ( [0] => Scientists )

**Expected Ouput:**

Array ( [0] => Scientists [1] => "[('Scientists', 'NNS')]" [2] => "Done!")

When I run the command manually it takens around 5-10 sec to run. [This may be due to the time required to do POS tagging or importing nltk.]

But when run through PHP it immediately returns and output from nltk.pos_tag or print statement after it is not returned.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the value of $tmp and are you sure that $string2 is set to 'Scientists'?  What happens if you print out something at the top of the python script?

Comment: @msgmash.com $tmp does not print anything. Anything at the top i.e before nltk.pos_tag is printed.

Comment: 2>&1 needs to be added in the command to get the complete output.

Comment: are you running the php file at the command line or through a browser?  also, did @vaicidrewar's advice help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2>&1 needs to be added in the command to get the complete output.
This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [shell_exec](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) – or, if you want to have more control, proc_open – instead of exec().